# Passing values to html/template outside of handler

Tags: go

I would like to pass a struct which contains all of my admin/system values to my view, which is parsed using html/template in Go.  For example, I would like to give .IsAuthenticated and .IsAdmin to my view by default, without explicitly passing it through the handler.

Is it possible to make these values always available by default, without passing through a handler?  I would like to pass form values and other user generated content through the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for the template to access the admin/system struct without the application passing the value to the template. A convenient way to to pass the value is through an anonymous field in each view type. Here's an example:

Assuming that `AdminStuff` is the struct containing your admin and system data and `getAdminSystemStuff(*http.Request)` is a function that gets a pointer to the struct from a request, define the view data like this:

```
func myHandler(w http.Response, r *http.Request) {
  var data = struct {
    *AdminSystemStuff
    AFieldSpecificToThisView string
    AnotherViewField string
  }{
    getAdminSystemStuff(r),
    "hello",
    "world"
  }
  err := t.Execute(w, &data)  // t is the compiled template.
  if err != nil {
     // handle error
  }
}
```

You can use this in a template like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Here are some fields: {{.AFieldSpecificToThisView}} {{.AnotherViewField}}
{{if .IsAuthenticated}}The user is authenticated{{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to add this to my example app, but I'm not sure where certain components go (such as the struct.)  Would you mind posting the file name for each section so I can see how to reproduce this?  I'm very new to Go!

Comment: Thank you very much for the revision - I see how this works now!